# Customizing Native Base with expo (colors not changing)

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

For some reason I'm not able to get the customize stuff to work. Starting with common color. 
What I've done:

- export Native Base
- went into common color file and change them
- went into my page and imported getTheme
- wrapped the page in StyleProvider
- But still nothing changed :(

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

getTheme() should receive a parameter which is a theme file.

import material from './native-base-theme/variables/material';
getTheme(material)

Also try to rebuild the app.

Comment: This is what I did but it still did not work. The primary button turned blank and I have changed the colors in the common color file but still nothing. I'm importing these into one of my files. 

import getTheme from '../../native-base-theme/components';
import material from "../../native-base-theme/variables/material";

<StyleProvider style={getTheme(material)}>